# Remove duplicate values from view - Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular8, themoviedb-api

Below are duplicated fields i want to filter and just display one instead of both:

"release_dates":[
{"**certification":"PG-13","iso_639_1**":"","note":"Telluride Film Festival","release_date":"2018-08-31T00:00:00.000Z","type":1},

{"**certification":"PG-13","iso_639_1"**:"","note":"","release_date":"2018-09-28T00:00:00.000Z","type":2}]}]}

component below display both records from above json:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { MoviesService } from '../movies.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie',
  templateUrl: './movie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie.component.css']
})
export class MovieComponent implements OnInit {
  movie: Object;
  certification: Array<Object>;
  video: Object;
  constructor(
    private _moviesServices: MoviesService,
    private router: ActivatedRoute
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.params.subscribe((params) => {
      const id = params['id'];
      this._moviesServices.getMovie(id).subscribe(movie => {
        this.movie = movie;
      });
      this._moviesServices.getCertification(id).subscribe((res: any) => {
        const usCertifications = res.results.filter((result: any) => {
          return result.iso_3166_1 === "US";
          // return this.certification === result.certificationAll;
        });
        this.certification = usCertifications;
      });

    })

  }

}
```

html:

```
<div class="mr-3" *ngIf="certification"><span *ngFor="let cert of certification">
          <span *ngFor="let release of cert.release_dates">
            <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning" *ngIf="release.certification">{{release.certification}}</span>
          </span>
        </span>
      </div>
```

Comment: Well those two are not duplicate values. They are different. One has a `note`, other does not, also release date is different. So based on what should they be filtered?

Comment: And what is the actual response you get initially from `getCertification`, can you add a sample?

Comment: yes i tried filtering by note keeping in mind but some of the places it's not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a leap and assume you want to filter out the duplicates based on the `certification` property, so we can use `filter()` to do that. If it's not that property, just change the property you want to filter by in below code. Also I would assume that from the original response you get, you only want one object (US certificates), so no need to make an array with `filter()`, instead use `find()`. With that we get only one object. So I suggest the following:

```ts
certifications = [];

// ...

this._moviesServices.getCertification(id).subscribe((res: any) => {
  const uscerts = this.results.find((result: any) => (result.iso_3166_1 === "US"));

  if (uscerts && uscerts.release_dates && uscerts.release_dates.length) {
    this.certifications = uscerts.release_dates.filter((item, i, arr) =>
      // filter by what prop you want, here we use certification
      arr.findIndex((x) => (x.certification === item.certification)) === i);
  } else {
    this.certifications = [];
  }
});
```

Now you can iterate the array you have in `this.certifications`:

```html
<span *ngFor="let release of certifications">
  {{release.certification}}
</span>
```

**[DEMO: StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpwyy3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Also I would suggest you actually use a model for your data, not use `any`. Makes your life so much easier, when the IDE can warn you if you try to do something wrong ;)

Comment: Thank you for the help i think this was the easiest solution for me to fix this.  I just added ngIf in case if no data it should restrict the badge(designer ui badge) to apear in view. Yes i will use the model. currently struggling with migrating from angularjs to latest. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a function to remove duplicates in your component or use a pipe to do the same thing
Something similar to this

```
result:any=[];
removeDuplicates(): any{
   this.certification.forEach((item)=>{
        if(this.result.indexOf(item) < 0) {
            this.result.push(item);
        }
   });
return this.result;
}
```

And then call it in template

```
<div class="mr-3" *ngIf="certification"><span *ngFor="let cert of removeDuplicates(certification)">
          <span *ngFor="let release of cert.release_dates">
            <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning" *ngIf="release.certification">{{release.certification}}</span>
          </span>
        </span>
      </div>
```

Comment: @ user8351493 I have added the full component code and tried but getting some error

Comment: What is the error? I have edited function inside forEach to use arrowNotation. Try if that works

Comment: i have just added that function after ngOnInit() and again added your update but getting the same duplicates. after addeing arrowNotation no error but again same duplicates PG-13 twice

Answer (score 1):

You can write a pipe where in it takes the array and returns the non duplicate items.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'duplicate' })
export class DuplicatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(elements: any[]) {
     let result = [];
     elements.forEach(element => {
      if (!elements.find(fEle => fEle.certification === element.certification)) {
        result.push(element);
      }
    });
  return result;
  }
}
```

and in the template:

```
<div class="mr-3" *ngIf="certification"><span *ngFor="let cert of certification">
          <span *ngFor="let release of cert.release_dates | duplicate">
            <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning" *ngIf="release.certification">{{release.certification}}</span>
          </span>
        </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to remove duplicates based on just `certification` property.

**Component:**

Add below `removeDuplicates()` function in your component.

We are using JavaScript [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object to keep track of duplicates.

```
removeDuplicates(certification): any {
    certification.forEach((item) => {
      var filteredResults = new Map();

      item['release_dates'].forEach((value) => {
        if (!filteredResults.has(value.certification)) {
          filteredResults.set(value.certification, value);
        }
      });

      item['release_dates'] = [];

      filteredResults.forEach((value, key) => {
        item['release_dates'].push(value);
      });
    });

    return certification;
  }
```

**HTML:**

In your HTML call `removeDuplicates()` function in `*ngFor` as shown below.

```
<div class="mr-3" *ngIf="certification">
    <span *ngFor="let cert of removeDuplicates(certification)">
    <span *ngFor="let release of cert.release_dates">
      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning" *ngIf="release.certification">{{release.certification}}<br></span>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

You can see it live on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4yklwe